# Obtaining differential equation with separated variables

Tags: differential-equations

I have a partial differential equation in $F(x,y)$. It is known that the solution is separable i.e. $F(x,y)=f(x)g(y)$ for some unknown functions $f$ and $g$. Can Mathematica express the differential equation in $F(x,y)$ in terms of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$?

Note: I don't care about the explicit solution here. I only want Mathematica to output the differential equation in terms of $f$ and $g$, given the differential equation in terms of $F(x,y)$.

Comment: Define your multi-variable function `F[x_, y_] := f[x] g[x]`, and put `F` back into the PDE to see what happens.

Comment: Check out [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/157174/how-to-solve-analytically-a-2d-sturm-liouville-problem/159248#159248)